# expression language - header value is null

Tags: jsp, foreach, el

In .jsp pages by using Expression Language, i am wanting to retrieve all header names along with their values.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${pageContext.request.headerNames}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>${item}</td>
        <td>${header["${item}"]}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

header is as far as i know a map

- The quotation marks are required for specifying a property in a JavaBean or a **key in a map**

But `<td>${header["${item}"]}</td>` return null, even though `<td>${item}</td>` return the header name.

Comment: This is not an duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>${header["${item}"]}</td>
```

should be

```
<td>${header[item]}</td>
```

Alternatively you could use the implicit header object in jstl

```
<c:forEach items = "header" var = "h">

Header Name ${h.key}
Header Value ${h.value}

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Without quotation mark in my example = Failed to parse the expression [${header[${item}]}] but it worked like a charm to iterate over the header object and get the key and value.

Comment: Please look carefully :), the item does not have a '$' or a '{' surrounding it. Its just plain [item]

Comment: I see now, been looking at this for too long xD I tried it out but i get an javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ScopeMap$ScopeEntry cannot be cast to java.lang.String --- <td>${header[item]}</td>

Comment: Oh wow, its a Map.Entry. Maybe you should try item.key in place of item. Sorry I dont have a working environment to try it out

Comment: Than it works :)